# Equality of pointers to classes in hierarchy

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, memory-address

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() : m_i(0) { }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }

protected:
    double m_d;
};

class C
    : public A
    , public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') { }

private:
    char m_c;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A *pa = &c;
    B *pb = &c;

    const int x = (pa == &c) ? 1 : 2;
    const int y = (pb == &c) ? 3 : 4;
    const int z = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)) ? 5 : 6;

    std::cout << x << y << z << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code prints out `136` which would suggest that the first equality was true, second also but not the third. Since `pa` and `pb` are both set to `&c` the first two would make sense but then why would the third equality be false?

I ran this code in Visual C++ 2012 and used debugger to check the addresses:

```
pa == 0x003bfc90
pb == 0x003bfc98
&c == 0x003bfc90
```

Apparently, `pa` and `pb` don't point to the same address which would mean that the third equality should be false (and it is). But then why are the first two true? Could you explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: The compiler automatically adds offsets to the pointer location based on the type. Your cast prevents this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two pointers do indeed have different values since they point to different sub-objects of `c`; these two objects must exist at different locations.

Without `reinterpret_cast`, the equality comparison first looks for a suitable conversion to the same pointer type. This converts `&c` from `C*` to `B*` by modifying the pointer value to point to the `B` sub-object of `c` - exactly the same conversion that was applied when initialising `pb`. After that conversion, both pointers have the same value, and so compare equal.

`reinterpret_cast` means that the pointer should be converted to the target type without modifying its value, whether or not that conversion is meaningful. So, after that conversion, the pointers still have different values, and compare not equal.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` _can_ modify the pointer value, in the case where different pointer types have a different representation or size.  I've worked on a number of machines where casting a `char*` to an `int*` would have modified the value, for example.  (Of course, this was before the days of C++.)  Such machines are rare today, if they even still exist, however; and even in them, all pointers to a class type would have to use the same representation, and so would be unchanged.